# Cross-thread work with Control which have a data source (ComboBox)

Tags: c#, multithreading, user-interface, controls

At first I will post the code, it is short and quite clear.
**cb_currentProfile** is a ComboBox filled with 3 items when form is loaded:

```
delegate void SetCurrentProfileCallback(int index);

private void SetCurrentProfile(int index) // Set index of Combobox.SelectedItem
{
    if (this.cb_currentProfile.InvokeRequired)
    {
        SetCurrentProfileCallback d = new SetCurrentProfileCallback(SetCurrentProfile);
        this.Invoke(d, new object[] { index });
    }
    else
    {
        this.cb_currentProfile.SelectedItem = 2;            // Won't work
        this.cb_currentProfile.Visible = false;             // It works
    }
}
```

The problem is that when I try to change **SelectedItem** property, then it won't do nothing (no crash, just nothing happens).

I am sure that this code is reached in my form application.

At now I am making it in .NET 4.6 (but it was not working in v4.5 either)

The place where I am calling this method is in **Task** body:

```
Task.Run(() =>
{
    while(true)
    {
        // ...
        SetCurrentProfile(2);
        // ...
        Thread.Sleep(100);
    }
});
```

I think that the problem is related to DataSource that seems to be invisible by other thread than main UI's.

I am also sure that data are loaded to ComboBox before code reaches a Task creation.

**Edit 1 - selected item is null, Count property returns 0**

When I used a debugger to check for some data, the results are:

```
var x = this.cb_currentProfile.SelectedItem; // null
var y = this.cb_currentProfile.Items.Count;  // 0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like, with the `this.cb_currentProfile.SelectedItem = 2` statement, you intend to set the selection of the `ComboBox` by *index*. The [ComboBox.SelectedItem Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.selecteditem%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) accepts an `Object` and attempts to find it in its collection of items, selecting it if successful, and doing nothing otherwise. To select a particular index of the `ComboBox`, set the [ComboBox.SelectedIndex Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.selectedindex%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead.

Comment: I should mention that I was thinking about this, and there is nothing wrong with setting an item by *index* (as long as it exists).

I used a debugger to give me some tips, and
`var x = this.cb_currentProfile.SelectedItem;`
resulted in null value